# What is the correct fast way to compare two `Uint8List`s' equality?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Given `Uint8List a = ...; Uint8List b = ...;` I want to compare whether their content are the same. Of course I can use `listEquals` in Flutter, or write down a naive loop like:

```
for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index += 1) {
    if (a[index] != b[index])
      return false;
  }
```

However, given that `Uint8List` is quite a special array, and it is often quite big, I guess where there is a better (faster) approach to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you should be able to get some slight speed-up by comparing bytes 4 or 8 bytes at a time (which also should have alignment benefits).  This should not need to copy the byte data and therefore would not have a significant memory penalty.  I wrote a quick implementation to try it:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:math' show Random;

/// Naive [List] equality implementation.
bool listEquals<E>(List<E> list1, List<E> list2) {
  if (identical(list1, list2)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (list1.length != list2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i += 1) {
    if (list1[i] != list2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

/// Compares two [Uint8List]s by comparing 8 bytes at a time.
bool memEquals(Uint8List bytes1, Uint8List bytes2) {
  if (identical(bytes1, bytes2)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (bytes1.lengthInBytes != bytes2.lengthInBytes) {
    return false;
  }

  // Treat the original byte lists as lists of 8-byte words.
  var numWords = bytes1.lengthInBytes ~/ 8;
  var words1 = bytes1.buffer.asUint64List(0, numWords);
  var words2 = bytes2.buffer.asUint64List(0, numWords);

  for (var i = 0; i < words1.length; i += 1) {
    if (words1[i] != words2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Compare any remaining bytes.
  for (var i = words1.lengthInBytes; i < bytes1.lengthInBytes; i += 1) {
    if (bytes1[i] != bytes2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

void main() {
  var random = Random();

  // Generate random data.
  //
  // 100 MB minus a few bytes to avoid being an exact multiple of 8 bytes.
  const numBytes = 100 * 1000 * 1000 - 3;
  var data = Uint8List.fromList([
    for (var i = 0; i < numBytes; i += 1) random.nextInt(256),
  ]);

  var dataCopy = Uint8List.fromList(data);

  var stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  var result = listEquals(data, dataCopy);
  print('Naive:     $result ${stopwatch.elapsed}');

  stopwatch
    ..reset()
    ..start();
  result = memEquals(data, dataCopy);
  print('memEquals: $result ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
}
```

My empirical results from running it as a Dart console application on my 64-bit Linux machine (`dart mem_equals.dart`):

```
Naive:     true 0:00:00.152984
memEquals: true 0:00:00.038664
```

and from compiling it (`dart compile exe mem_equals.dart && mem_equals.exe`):

```
Naive:     true 0:00:00.093478
memEquals: true 0:00:00.033560
```

As a baseline, a pure C program calling `memcmp` on an identically sized byte array (`clang -O3 memcmp_test.c && a.out`) on the same system takes about 0.011s.

With `dart:ffi`, unfortunately [there currently is no way to pass a `Uint8List`](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/issues/27#issuecomment-553455762), so an existing `Uint8List` must first be copied to a C memory buffer.  For a large amount of data, the extra allocation and copy will dominate the runtime cost.  If, however, you start off with an appropriately allocated `Pointer<Uint8>` and use [`.asTypedList`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/Uint8Pointer/asTypedList.html) when you need to pass it to Dart code, then the runtime cost should be about the same as `memcmp`.

Comment: Indeed I was wondering whether a C++ implementation instead of dart will be faster, since C++ loops should have very little overhead. But your solution seems already quite good

Answer (score 1):

Dart's `listEquals` does exactly what your code does (plus a few shortcut checks) so I would use that instead of your own code, as it's cleaner.  One possible alternative is to convert both lists to `String` and do a `String` equality comparison. I doubt that it is faster (because it creates a new `String`), but your could easily benchmark that and decide!

To convert a `UInt8List` to a `String` use

```
String s = String.fromCharCodes(inputAsUint8List);
```